# Issues with explicit cursor

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, cursor

Im currently taking a PL/SQL class and learning about explicit cursors. Im working on an assignment right now and am having issues with the following problem.

'In this assignment use an explicit cursor to display the below table. If there is a ‘Y’ in the V_ORDER of the VENDOR table then print out the vendor’s name from the VENDOR table followed by the text ' supplies the product:  ' followed by the description of the item supplied from the PRODUCT table.'

I have developed the following block...

[cursor block][1]

And get the following error...(this is using oracle apex)
[error msg][2]

Im waiting for a response from my professor but he can be slow (online course). Any input would be greatly appreciated!

updated block...

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_vendor IS
SELECT v.v_order, p.p_descript
FROM vendor v INNER JOIN product p
USING (v_code)
WHERE v.v_order = 'Y';
TYPE type_vendor IS RECORD(
name vendor.v_name%TYPE,
descript product.p_descript%TYPE);
rec_vendor type_vendor;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_vendor;
LOOP
FETCH cur_vendor INTO rec_vendor;
EXIT WHEN cur_vendor%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_vendor;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_vendor.name || ' supplies the product ' || 
rec_vendor.descript);
END;
```

Comment: Kindly post code and not screen shot/links.

Comment: Heres an updated block that is only returning one value...It should be returning 11. Is there an issue with my loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_vendor IS
SELECT v.v_order, v.v_name, p.p_descript FROM product p 
natural JOIN vendor 
v;
TYPE type_vendor IS RECORD(
v_order vendor.v_order%TYPE,
v_name vendor.v_name%TYPE,
descript product.p_descript%TYPE);
rec_vendor type_vendor;
BEGIN 
OPEN cur_vendor;
LOOP
FETCH cur_vendor INTO rec_vendor;
EXIT WHEN cur_vendor%NOTFOUND;
IF rec_vendor.v_order = 'Y' THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_vendor.v_name||' supplies the product ' || 
rec_vendor.descript);
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_vendor;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty specific, you are using the reserved word "desc" as a column name. Either change the column name to a non-reserved word, or enclose it in double quotes with each use.

Comment: *attribute name in the record type definition, but yes, certainly a reserved word issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I changed it as you will see. after some tinkering, i have it working but it is only returning one row and im not sure why (it should be returning 11) and its also putting the value of v_order where v_name should be in the DBMS output? is there an issue with my loop perhaps?

Comment: DECLARE
CURSOR cur_vendor IS
SELECT v.v_order, p.p_descript
FROM vendor v INNER JOIN product p
USING (v_code)
WHERE v.v_order = 'Y';
TYPE type_vendor IS RECORD(
name vendor.v_name%TYPE,
descript product.p_descript%TYPE);
rec_vendor type_vendor;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_vendor;
LOOP
FETCH cur_vendor INTO rec_vendor;
EXIT WHEN cur_vendor%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_vendor;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_vendor.name || ' supplies the product ' || rec_vendor.descript);
END;

Comment: @GilesBonner - Edit your question to include your code, don't post a bunch of code in a comment.   Put your code in your question, don't link to an image of code.